# How to identify commits that bypassed gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

My knowledge of git is minimal, apologize in advance for any wrong terminology use.

I know that `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master` creates a gerrit review and `git push origin HEAD:master` pushes to the remote repository, bypassing gerrit.

How do I identify commits that were pushed straight to the remote git repository, bypassing gerrit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [Gerrit Query](https://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3021/documentation/2.1.4/cmd-query.html) feature to get information about code reviews. For example:

1. get a list of all your commits;
2. try to query information about each commit in list by running `ssh
   ${GERRIT_HOST} gerrit query --all-reviewers project:${PROJECTNAME}
   commit:${COMMIT_HASH}`;
3. if result is empty, then commit has been pushed directly, without
   code review;